# Battle my own Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

This morning I fought a gym, with success. I captured it and placed my own Pokemon in it. I thought I could place another one, but instead of that, I was fighting against my own (just placed) Pokemon?

Does this cost health (and thus potions/revives)? What benefits does this have?

Comment: I’m closing this question as the referenced mechanic of battling one's own Pokemon on a gym is [no longer applicable](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/948/28182)  to the current version of Pokemon Go. The concept of 'training' and Gym prestige has been replaced with the ['motivation'](https://pokemongo.fandom.com/wiki/Gym) mechanic as of June 2017.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A gym can store one Pokemon per gym level, and only one Pokemon per player. If you already have a Pokemon parked at a particular gym, you cannot put another one there.

You can raise your gym level by raising its **Prestige**, at 2000 prestige per gym level. This is done by **training** at the gym, pitching **one** of your Pokemon against the gym's roster. The more Pokemon you defeat, the more Prestige that is awarded.

For example, my 337 Golem was taking down my local gym's 3 Pokemon at 433 Prestige per run. I did this from 6000 to 8000 Prestige so that I could park my Pokemon in the newly available slot.

Consequently, attackers follow the opposite pattern. With a roster of **six** Pokemon, they will attempt to defeat the Pokemon at the gym. Doing so reduces the Prestige. Once the Prestige is low enough to de-level the gym, the lowest-CP Pokemon is kicked out. This is done until the gym hits 0 Prestige, from which it goes uncontrolled. Then anyone near the uncontrolled gym can claim it.

There is currently no way to restore a Pokemon's health aside from items. Potions are your friend.

Comment: Based on my experience, it's definitely not the lowest CP pokemon that gets kicked out when a gym level drops. I *think* it's the most recent one to have been added, but I've not been able to verify that.

Comment: @me_and I added my 337 Golem to a gym that consisted of a 10 CP Pidgey and a pair of ~150 Pidgeottos. It was brought down a level an hour later, and the Pidgey was kicked out. Monitoring the two gyms near me, which are on public transit lines, I have observed all drops in gym levels to kick out the lowest level Pokemon.

Comment: Gym level prestige requirements double per level I think, it's not a flat 2000 increase